# YellowBrick SilhouetteVisualizer does not seem to take my model, and when fit itself it assumes two different length of timeseries

Tags: cluster-analysis

I use TimeSeriesKMeans from tslearn.clustering, and when trying to visualize the silhouettescore using yellowbrick SilhouetteVisualizer I get an image, but also a few messages I cannot understand why.

Also, when I pass the model to SilhouetteVisualizer and input is_fitted=True it still does not seem to accept it; I still have to use  visualizer.fit(cluster_data) to be able to show an image.

Some code

```
    km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=number_of_clusters, metric='euclidean', verbose=True, random_state=0)
    y_pred = km.fit_predict(cluster_data)
    
    plt.figure()
    visualizer = SilhouetteVisualizer(km, X=cluster_data, y=y_pred, is_fitted=True, colors='yellowbrick')
    visualizer.fit(cluster_data)        # I have to use this to be able to show the visualizer
    visualizer.show()
```

When I run the code like this I get an image, but also information in the console that:

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\Clustering\lib\site-packages\tslearn\utils\utils.py:90: UserWarning:

2-Dimensional data passed. Assuming these are 7 1-dimensional timeseries

C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\Clustering\lib\site-packages\tslearn\utils\utils.py:90: UserWarning:

2-Dimensional data passed. Assuming these are 110 1-dimensional timeseries
```

The cluster_data in this case is of shape (110,24), i.e. 110 daily time series of hourly resolution.

If I skip the visualizer.fit(cluster_data) row I get the error message:

```
*** yellowbrick.exceptions.YellowbrickAttributeError: neither visualizer 'SilhouetteVisualizer' nor wrapped estimator 'TimeSeriesKMeans' have attribute 'n_samples_'
```

I've tried to read the documents but am a little stuck. Is it because I use the "wrong" input model to it?

That SilhouetteVisualizer would take the fitted model and use it wihtout have to fit it again, or output assumptions of the size of the time series